# Select string after a number of signs

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a text file like this:

> AE, R, CZ
>
> DRY, EQV, FVC
>
> G, HLONN, IPO

I want to delete the third comma & what comes next using regex.

> AE, R
>
> DRY, EQV
>
> G, HLONN

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a replace with this search pattern

```
([^,]*,[^,]*),.*
```

And this replacement pattern

```
\1
```

Make sure to have '. matches new line' unchecked.

[image: replace box]

---

**Update:**

If your text can have fewer than three commas per line, this search pattern would probably be safer:

```
(.*?,.*?),.*
```

Comment: Or simply replace `,[^,]+$` with nothing.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal Yes I considered that but OP said 'third comma' not 'last comma'.